# Laravel's getAttributes() method ignoring custom attribute accessors

Tags: php, attributes, laravel-5.4, accessor

I basically wan't to create a table based on all my model's attributes with Laravel, but the problem is, that the `getAttributes()` method ignores my custom added accessors even though I've added the name of the property to the `$appends` property (which adds it to json and array convertions). But still, I can't get my custom property. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access to all model attributes (including the `Model::$appends` attributes)  by calling the `Model::attributesToArray()` method. Here is an example.

```
$modelAttributes = $model->attributesToArray();

$modelAttributeNames = array_keys($modelAttributes);
```

Comment: Nice and very useful

Comment: Laravel 10.x in 2024... anyone care to suggest why `$model->getAttributes()` ignores the model casts?